# How to fix reading from file after using std::cin function

Tags: c++, fstream

I have some problem with my C++ code.

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    string line;
    fstream file("file.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::app);

    cout << "enter your text  :";
    cin >> s;
    file << s;
    cout << "\ndata file contains :";

    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        cout << "\n" << line;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
enter your text : alikamel // for example
then write it to file
data file contains : // file contents
```

But I get this instead:

```
enter your text : ass // for example
and it write it to file
then display
data file contains : // nothing ??
```

Why doesn't it display the file contents, what is wrong?

Comment: Try 1) Flush the `file` before reading from the file; this ensures that all of the data is written from the buffers to the file.  2) You may want to rewind or seek to the beginning of the file (to update the file pointer and status).

Comment: You need to append a newline to the file.  The statement `file << s` only writes `s`, which doesn't have a newline in it.  The `getline` function is looking for a newline.

Comment: Also, change the name of your variable `file`.  Since you are using `namespace std;`, you don't want your variable `file` confused with any `std::file` symbol.  **Or**, you could get rid of `using namespace std;` and use the prefix `std::`.

Comment: I would use a `std::ofstream` to write to the file, and a separate `std::ifstream` to read from the file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That shouldn't affect the output much. `getline` will stop reading when it hits EOF and give the extracted string. The fail flag is only set if no characters are read as a result of reaching EOF, which means `while(getline(file, line))` works fine regardless of whether the file ends in a line break.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang yes, however, the code is *appending* new text to an existing file, so if a newline is never written, `getline()` will always read the *entire* file contents in one go, not read it line-by-line in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems is that you are trying to read from the end of the file.

`fstream` holds a pointer to the current position in the file. 
After you finish writing to file, this pointer points to the end, ready for the next write command.

So, when you are trying to read from the file without moving the pointer, you are trying to read from the end of the file.

You need to use `seekg` to move to the beginning of the file to read what you wrote:

```
file << s;
cout << "\ndata file contains :";

file.seekg(0);

while(getline(file, line))
{
    cout << "\n" << line;
}
```

Comment: what about seekp() function ?

Comment: @alikamel what about it? This function is for `ofstream` object. If you were using such object to write to file, you would need to call it. But it is not relevant to your example. Note that a `fstream` object has only one file pointer. There is always one position in the file that you will work with. If you want to read in one place and write to another you will need to move the pointer between operations.

Comment: One small thing I forgot to mention: reading the entire stream with `getline` will set `eof` error state on the stream, which will prevent any further write operations until you call `file.clear()`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the file is empty, in that case, you can do something like this

```
    fstream file("TestFile.txt", ios::out); 

    cout << "enter your text  :";
    cin >> s;                          // Take the string from user 
    file << s;                         // Write that string in the file
    file.close();                      // Close the file

    file.open("TestFile.txt",ios::in);
    cout << "data file contains :" << endl;
    while(getline(file, line)) {       //Take the string from file to a variable
        cout << line << endl;          // display that variable
    }
    file.close();
    cin.get();
```

And as one of the comment mentions... you can use the `ifstream` and `ofstream` as well for better undersanding